# How to prevent Pinch IN Zooming of Image using Pinchzoom.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, zooming, pinchzoom

So I have this scenario where I am using [Pinchzoom.js](https://github.com/manuelstofer/pinchzoom) library for zooming images. It is perfectly working and the library is very good. But I have a scenario where the PINCH IN gesture (on mobile) also makes the image zoom OUT. To see a working demo, you can refer to their working [demo link](https://manuelstofer.github.io/pinchzoom/demo/pinchzoom.html). When you will PINCH IN, you will observe that the image zooms OUT but after the gesture has ended, it retains its original size. I wanted to ask if there is a way to disable this zooming out effect? My `PinchZoom` settings are as:

```
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.myimages')).forEach(function (el) {
        new PinchZoom.default(el, {
            tapZoomFactor: 5,
            maxZoom: 10,
            use2d: true,
            verticalPadding: 1,
            draggableUnzoomed: false
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the property minZoom to 1.

This effect happens because it allows you to zoom out to a size that is smaller than your screen, so the browser scale it back so it fits the whole phone width.

Comment: Works good. I had to clear the cache to see the effect. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the property which will tell the minimum zoom size. In **Pinchzoom.js** library there is **minZoom property** for that.

So if you **don't** want your image to be zoomed out on pinch-in then set **minZoom:1**.

I tried this settings by adding minZoom property to the demo link and it was working correctly.

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.myimages-container')).forEach(function (el) {
        new PinchZoom.default(el, {
            tapZoomFactor: 5,
            maxZoom: 10,
            minZoom:1,
            use2d: true,
            verticalPadding: 1,
            draggableUnzoomed: false
        });
    });
```

If this solution is not working for you then maybe this is the problem is with your element selection.

Use **container** `<div>` as the parent of your every image and then apply settings to that parent `<div>`.

```
<div class="myimages-container">
<img src="my_image.jpg"></img>
</div>
```

Comment: Works good. I had to clear the cache to see the effect. Thanks.